# Can't reference Portable Class Library from Windows Runtime Component

Tags: c#, c++

VS 2015 keeps giving me 'A reference cannot be added because the two projects target different platforms' errors when I try to reference my (.Net Framework 4.5 + Windows 8) PCL from my (C++) Windows 10 Runtime Component.

- Must I retarget my PCL (to what)?
- Why does it happen?

[Meanwhile I found an excellent article by Oren Novotny ([Demystifying PCL’s, .NET Core, DNX and UWP](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/)) that helped a bit but the matrix at the end led me to believe my netcore45/net45 PCL should be consumed by UWP.]

Comment: Back in the day the word was "DLL hell" but with current .NET it has gotten worse, imho. I also spent quite some hours pondering which framework I need for all my dlls I use to work.

Comment: It is a pretty basic mismatch, your C++ component doesn't use .NET at all.  So it can't use a PCL library, only a WinRT library.  The usual source of this confusion is the C++/CX language extension syntax, backgrounder [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32221354/17034).